# How do I validate a password typed into a scala.swing.passwordfield?

Tags: swing, scala, passwords

I am currently working on a login system for an application using scala 2.9.1. My question is how do I validate a password that is entered into a **passwordfield** since the returned string is encrypted. I would think there is a simple .command for password matching? Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: Is this Lift-specific?  You should use the appropriate tag, or at least mention what it is in the text of the question.

Comment: @rex-kerr, this seems Swing-specific, nothing about Lift.

Comment: @Ivan - The case confused me.  `PasswordField` is not `passwordfield`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the method `password` to obtain the entered text and do whatever you like. I don't think there is any encryption.

What might be notable is that `password` returns an array of `Char` and not a String. You can use `password.mkString` to turn it into a `String`.

```
scala> import swing._
import swing._

scala> val frame = new MainFrame
MainFrame   

scala> val frame = new MainFrame
frame: scala.swing.MainFrame <snip>

scala> val pwf = new PasswordField
pwf: scala.swing.PasswordField = <snip>

scala> frame.contents = pwf
frame.contents: Seq[scala.swing.Component] = <snip>

scala> frame.open

scala> pwf.password
res1: Array[Char] = Array(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

Comment: I checked again, and it is returning a value but you have to use this method to evaluate. passwordvariable.password.mkString.equals("password")

Comment: @m3.0 I didn't quite understand your comment. Maybe you're refering to the fact that an `Array[Char]` is returned instead of a `String`? Please see my edit. And if you think I completely answers your question, please accept my answer by clicking the green check-mark.